# Format multiple rows of Excel Cells if they are not between a range

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a low number and a high number in columns A and B respectively. In columns C thru Z I have numbers.

This pattern repeats down many rows with a different low and high for each row.

I'm trying to conditionally format any cell in columns C thru Z if they fall outside of the two numbers...and then move to the next row and do the same with the new low and high values.

I tried using the conditional formatting feature in Excel 2010, but it didn't seem to work when I tried to use anchors for the low and high columns.  Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need VBA - try this:

Select columns C to Z

Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > In the formula box type this formula

`=AND(C1<>"",OR(C1<$A1,C1>$B1))`

select required format > OK

That should be all you require - make sure formula is exactly as above including $ signs

Comment: + 1 For the Non VBA Approach :)

Comment: You would think that would work, but it's inconsistent as hell--some cells are evaluated properly and others aren't!  There are no formulas involved, just manually entered numbers...Thanks!